# Percona xtradb Backup for OLTP

Tags: mysql, backup, percona, xtradb

I have installed MySQL 5.7 community edition installed.
Can we use Percona xtradb backup tool for backup DB for banking site databases for OLTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percona is a very popular and reputed company. Their products also meet some compliance. So there is nothing to say NO. But you mentioned that this is for Bank. Many banks have their own compliance. So, verify that you are authorized to use 3rd party software.

But the native `mysqldump` is not good for taking the large backup set. So its good to use `percona's xtra backup` or `mydumper`.

Comment: _Disclaimer: I work for Percona_ The answer is correct (thank you for that) and either of those solutions is likely to be appropriate. 
If you are researching and would like some metrics then I would happy to help you with stats and real-world examples of organizations using Percona XtraBackup (open source, free software) with OLTP and BI highly concurrent environments.